# Run CodedUI exe from Stand alone machine with least installation

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, coded-ui-tests

I have a requirement to click a button on an ASPX page remotely. I used coded ui to get an animated view of the click, then i created a windows forms application so that i now have an exe that can run the coded UI. Problem is when I run this exe from another standalone machine it does not work obviously because I do not have visual studio installed.

Please advise how i can get this exe to work and also if you have any alternative to CodedUI that does not require much installation, Please suggest.

Comment: What exactly does this magical button do?  You should be able to call the end point that it eventually calls and supply whatever information you need without having to go click that button.  Can you explain more about the system?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the free Microsoft test agent on any machine you need to run coded UI test without installing full Visual Studio. Make sure to install the same version as was used when developing the test.